# Are the Ubuntu App Developer Showdown Workshops recorded?

Tags: application-development

I am a new developer who wants to participate in the Ubuntu App Showdown. I would like to go to the Ubuntu App Developer Showdown Workshops but its abit hard with my schedule. Will these workshops be recorded? It would be nice so that I can watch these workshops later on.

Comment: Please remember to accept/upvote the best answer to your question (tick/check mark on the left). This way, the question is marked as "answered" and future readers can refer to it knowing the solution works. Thank you...:)

Answer (score 5):

Workshops can be seen live and are recorded to watch later on the [Ubuntu App Showdown Workshops page](http://developer.ubuntu.com/showdown/workshops/)